# Unable to get/download a file from Google Drive using the API

Tags: node.js, google-drive-api, fs

When I'm trying to get the file, my request goes through, but I end up with a file that is the correct type, but corrupt.

The file contains:

```
{
 "kind": "drive#file",
 "id": <ID of the File>,
 "name": <Name of the File>,
 "mimeType": <Type>
}
```

This is regardless of the file being an Image or Textfile.

```
function getFile(auth, file, path, call) {
  console.log(file)
  var dest = fs.createWriteStream(path + "/" + file.name);

  const drive = google.drive({version: 'v3', auth});
  drive.files.get({fileId: file.id, mimeType: 'image/jpeg'}, {responseType: "stream"},
    function(err, res) {
       res.data
       .on("end", () => {
          console.log("Done");
       })
       .on("error", err => {
          console.log("Error", err);
       })
       .pipe(dest);
    })
}
```

Answer (score 0):

How about this modification?

#### From:

```
drive.files.get({fileId: file.id, mimeType: 'image/jpeg'}, {responseType: "stream"},
```

#### To:

```
drive.files.get({fileId: file.id, alt: "media"}, {responseType: "stream"},
```

#### Note:

- files.get method in Drive API cannot convert the mimeType.
- If you want to export Google Docs (Spreadsheet, Document, Slides) by converting the mimeType, please modify above script as follows.

  ```
  drive.files.export({fileId: file.id, mimeType: 'image/jpeg'}, {responseType: "stream"},
  ```

#### Reference:

- [Download files](https://developers.google.com/drive/api/v3/manage-downloads)

If I misunderstood your question and this was not the result you want, I apologize.

Comment: I just tried it, but now it seems that my result is unidentified. The error I'm getting is {status: 403, statusText: 'Forbidden' }

Comment: @Ras. M Thank you for replying. I apologize for the inconvenience. In my environment, I can confirm that the modified script works. I apologize for this situation. So in order to correctly understand about your issue, can you provide whole script for replicating your current issue which posted as a comment? Of course, please remove your personal information. If you can do, please add it to your question. From this, I would like to confirm about the issue. If you can cooperate to resolve your issue, I'm glad.

Comment: @Ras. M And also I have 2 questions. 1. What mimeType of the original file do you want to download? 2. Are you owner of the file and the file is put in your Drive?